# Calling Py_Initialize() in multiple threads

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, c++11, python-embedding

I am embedding Python in a multi-threaded C++ application, is it safe to call 
`Py_Initialize()` in multiple threads? Or should I call it in the main thread?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it thread safe to modify a static variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837721/is-it-thread-safe-to-modify-a-static-variable)

Comment: You've already asked this question; albeit with a different focus. Please refer to my answer on the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The `Py_Initialize()` code contains:

```
if (initialized)
    return;
initialized = 1;
```

The documentation for the function also says:

- https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.Py_Initialize

> This is a no-op when called for a second time (without calling Py_Finalize() first).

My recommendation though is you only do it from the main thread, although depending on what you are doing, it can get complicated.

The problem is that signal handlers are only triggered in context of the main Python thread. That is, whatever thread was the one to call `Py_Initialize()`. So if that is a transient thread and is only used once and then discarded, then no chance to ever have signal handlers called. So you have to give some thought as to how you handle signals.

Also be careful of using lots of transient threads created in C code using native thread API and calling into Python interpreter as each will create data in the Python interpreter. That will accumulate if keep creating and discarding these external threads. You should endeavour to use a thread pool instead if calling in from external threads, and keep reusing prior threads.

Comment: If `Py_Initialize()` is called in multiple threads, how do you guarantee thread safety if one thread is reading this variable `initialized` while another thread is writing it to `1`?

Comment: Yes, that perhaps would be another issue. You would need to use a mutex lock around the call to ``Py_Initialize()`` in that case.